# Flickering on items update in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I'm currently fight with the problem, that the screen flickers when I add items to my ListView. (This is **not** about the colorCacheHint!)

I think the problem might be custom views I'm using but what should I implement to prevent already drawn items to be redrawn?

Comment: I am sorry I know it's been 3 months, but have you solved issue or you still need help?

Comment: Yes it is. My ListView-Items are RelativeLayouts with an ImageView and some TextViews. Do you know how I can add items without redraw everything in the list?

Comment: have you considered using `converView` tag technique?